# Drag and Drop file on Open / Save Dialog boxes to navigate to folder

Tags: mac, finder, ui

Just upgraded an old mac from High Sierra to Monterey (Thanks to OCLP) and I noticed that when I drag and drop a file on open and save windows it doesn't accept my file nor does it navigate to the file location. Am I missing something? When did this change happen and why is everyone okay with this? Thanks

Comment: I can't test whether it works or not because I have a 3rd party override to it. If it no longer works as it did, then maybe have a look at [Default Folder X](http://www.stclairsoft.com/DefaultFolderX/index.html) which enables this & much more. I've been using it since the 90s, before it even had the X.

Comment: @kevllar Can you reproduce this with any folder? For me, the issue started appearing   with Ventura, but it only happens with the Documents folder.

Comment: @mfilej I've since moved on to an Apple silicon mac so the issue is gone but have you tried updating to the latest version of Ventura? I just tested 13.2 on my Intel Mini and the issue resolved too. I think a workaround is to drag a file to border or frame of the open/save dialog window. If you drag it into the center it might copy or move the file but dragging to the frame borders will change locations. Maybe try that?

Comment: @kevllar thanks, I tried your suggestion, but no success. The thing is that this only happens with the Documents folder. I'm also on apple silicon, 13.3. Must be a different issue than yours. I'm glad yours was fixed!